# Where to start if I want to write a Custom Data Provider for EF 6.0

Tags: entity-framework

Do anyone have sample code for a Custom DataProvider for EF 6.0 ?

I want to write a DataProvider for a custom datastore in a CMS solution. I am not sure if this is possible or not, where to start.

Comment: Your CMS? Where your CMS will store its own data? As text files or any other database?

Comment: I think i misunderstood a few things. Was hoping I could build something for EF that didnt use a Database. Possible a set of text files, or a in memory object store.

Answer (score 2):

[EF provider and sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789835.aspx)
this was based on ef5, but the interface to a provider wont have changed much if at all.